# Slick Slider - Reference error: $ is not defined after terminal command node app.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, slick.js

I am working with Slick Carousel and I can't find the reason my Slick won't work if I use the node app.js command.

If I open index.html everything works fine. When I use the node app.js command it says: "Reference error: $ is not defined".

Here's my

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>bg designs</title>
```

(I tried option with)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(and as well without it) (I tried to reference it locally from my files as well)

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>
```

Here's my bottom of body

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

The first three lines of body bottom are copied from Slick carousel website.

In my app.js it looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.multiple-items').slick({
```

Of course after `.slick({` are settings which are not important because the carousel is working exactly the way I want it.

My point is to push it to Heroku so I can send preview website to my client. The problem is it has this problem where $ is not defined even when I think I'm referencing it properly.

Thank you for any NOT TOXIC answers. Have a nice day.

Comment: I think you don't fully understand what node.js is. You can use node.js to run server side javascript. As far as I can see you are trying to run client side javascript. What you need is a web server to serve your files a static assets. Have a look at [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or use nginx / apache for this.

Comment: I have installed express, I commented out the simple setup likeapp.get which is rendering index.html app listen aswell I'm requiring express. But it does the same thing. Even when it's commented out or when it's not.